# @Url.Action C# not working two parameters

Tags: c#, jquery

I am calling JQuery below that is working perfectly, but porID parameter is not sent correctly to the controller. Net instead of getting "porID" is "amp; porID". This was seen by the Network of Chrome ...

JQuery

```
oTable = $('#lista_cbo').dataTable({            
                "bServerSide": true,            
                "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("ListaGenerica", "Home", new { aController = "CBO", porID = true } )', 
                "bProcessing": true,
                "oSearch": {"sSearch": "" + id  + ""},
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",   
                "aoColumns": [
                            { "mDataProp": "CBOID", "sTitle": "ID", "sWidth": "16px" },
                            { "mDataProp": "Sigla", "sTitle": "Sigla", "sWidth": "64px" },
                            { "mDataProp": "Tipo", "sTitle": "Tipo", "sWidth": "64px" },
                            { "mDataProp": "Descricao", "sTitle": "Descrição" },                        
                            { "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "fnRender": function (o) {return '<a class="icone_16x16_detalhe" href=/CBO/Detalhar/' + o.aData["CBOID"] + '>D</a>';}}                          
                ],
            });
```

Controller C#

```
[HandleError]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult ListaGenerica(DataTables param, string aController, bool porID = false)
{
    var iniciaRegistrosEm = param.iDisplayStart;
    var totalRegistrosPorPagina = param.iDisplayLength;
    var totalColunas = param.iColumns;

    var result = ERP.Helpers.ListagemPadrao.ListaPadrao(
            aController, 
            param.iDisplayStart, 
            param.iDisplayLength,
            Request["mDataProp_" + param.iSortCol_0.ToString()],
            param.sSortDir_0,
            param.sSearch,
            porID
            );

    return Json(new
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iDisplayStart = param.iDisplayStart,
        iTotalRecords = result.TotalRegistros,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = result.TotalRegistrosVisualizados, 
        aaData = result.Dados 
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap @Url.Action with @Html.Raw:

```
@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ListaGenerica", "Home", new { aController = "CBO", porID = true } ))
```

java script probably is messing with '&' sign.

Answer (score 0):

looks nothing wrong with your code and assuming a get request your url should be something like this

```
Home/ListaGenerica/?acontroller=CBO&porId=true
```

which is correct and here because porId is a part of querystring &before its name is OK